# Auto height not covering the entire container

Tags: html, css, position

I am having an issue get a container's height to completely cover the text within the container. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong. I have set the height to auto, to try and solve this problem, but the height still does not cover all of the content.

Does anyone see anything I am doing wrong? If someone needs to see this live, I can give the site address in a comment.

[image]

```css
.light-gray {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  width: 34%;
}
.light-gray-container {
  /*margin: 100px 15% 0 15%;*/
  top: 150px;
  left: 15%;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
}
#things-to-know-title {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #000;
}
.things-to-know-bullets {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #606060;
  margin: 40px 15% 40px 0;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-gray">
  <div class="light-gray-container">
    <div id="things-to-know-title">THINGS TO KNOW</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">Although we are located in Ohio, we review and accept business projects from all over the world.</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">Take a few extra minutes to provide us with your specific project details as this will allow us to better evaluate the scope.</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">If you have a general inquiry you may email us directly.</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">We do a thorough evaluation of all projects and enjoy working with established brands that are open to a balance of strategic & creative solutions.</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">If you have an exceptional command of the English language and would like to write for our digital agency please email us.</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">If you have strong strategic, design or user experience skills and would like to Intern or work for Isadora Design please email us.</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Updated image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your css like this

Delete `top: 150px;` in `.light-gray-container` and add a `padding-top: 150px;` in `.light-gray`

```css
.light-gray {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  width: 34%;
  padding-top: 150px;
}
.light-gray-container {
  /*margin: 100px 15% 0 15%;*/
  left: 15%;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
}
#things-to-know-title {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #000;
}
.things-to-know-bullets {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #606060;
  margin: 40px 15% 0px 0;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-gray">
  <div class="light-gray-container">
    <div id="things-to-know-title">THINGS TO KNOW</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">Although we are located in Ohio, we review and accept business projects from all over the world.</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">Take a few extra minutes to provide us with your specific project details as this will allow us to better evaluate the scope.</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">If you have a general inquiry you may email us directly.</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">We do a thorough evaluation of all projects and enjoy working with established brands that are open to a balance of strategic & creative solutions.</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">If you have an exceptional command of the English language and would like to write for our digital agency please email us.</div>
    <div class="things-to-know-bullets">If you have strong strategic, design or user experience skills and would like to Intern or work for Isadora Design please email us.</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I get the container (light-gray) to naturally go to the bottom of the screen? I added a new image to my question. The small white gap is the distance to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Becky Updated my answer. Change your margin in `.things-to-know-bullets` to `margin: 40px 15% 0px 0;`

Comment: Awesome. That worked. Plus, I added a `padding-bottom: 40px;` to `light-gray-container` and that gave me the padding I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow:auto` to the div with class light-gray will solve your problem.

Comment: That kind of helps? It creates a scroll bar in between that div and the light-green one to the right of it.

Comment: @Becky try with: `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: That hid the overflow? Not sure why you said that.

Comment: @Becky it's useful in use with dynamic content and the overflow causing serious layout problems.